# Quartz scheduler not inserting its scheduler details in their configured database

Tags: java, jboss, quartz-scheduler, quartz

I'm using JBoss Application Server, I have two nodes of JBoss AS on different machines, on each node I have deployed two different EARs which contain different `quartz.properties`, and each EAR has its own database.

#### EAR 1 `quartz.properties` file configuration

```
org.quartz.scheduler.instanceName = Scheduler1
org.quartz.scheduler.instanceId = AUTO
org.quartz.threadPool.class = org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool
org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount = 1
org.quartz.threadPool.threadPriority = 5
org.quartz.jobStore.class = org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreCMT
org.quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateClass = org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.MSSQLDelegate
org.quartz.jobStore.tablePrefix = QRTZ_
org.quartz.jobStore.isClustered = true
org.quartz.jobStore.clusterCheckinInterval = 20000
org.quartz.jobStore.dataSource = CI
org.quartz.dataSource.CI.jndiURL = java:jboss/datasources/CI
org.quartz.jobStore.dataSource = nonManagedTX
org.quartz.dataSource.nonManagedTX.jndiURL = java:jboss/datasources/CI
org.quartz.jobStore.nonManagedTXDataSource = nonManagedTX
```

#### EAR 2 `quartz.properties` file configuration

```
org.quartz.scheduler.instanceName = Scheduler2
org.quartz.scheduler.instanceId = AUTO
org.quartz.threadPool.class = org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool
org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount = 1
org.quartz.threadPool.threadPriority = 5
org.quartz.jobStore.class = org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreCMT
org.quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateClass = org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.MSSQLDelegate
org.quartz.jobStore.tablePrefix = QRTZ_
org.quartz.jobStore.isClustered = true
org.quartz.jobStore.clusterCheckinInterval = 20000
org.quartz.jobStore.dataSource = CE
org.quartz.dataSource.CE.jndiURL = java:jboss/datasources/CE
org.quartz.jobStore.dataSource = nonManagedTX
org.quartz.dataSource.nonManagedTX.jndiURL = java:jboss/datasources/CE
org.quartz.jobStore.nonManagedTXDataSource = nonManagedTX
```

The problem is when I deployed EAR1 and EAR2 on JBoss AS, all configurations of EAR1 will be inserted into EAR2 database and vice versa, below are the tables in which Quartz data are stored.

1. QRTZ_CRON_TRIGGERS
2. QRTZ_JOB_DETAILS
3. QRTZ_LOCKS
4. QRTZ_SCHEDULER_STATE
5. QRTZ_SIMPLE_TRIGGERS
6. QRTZ_TRIGGERS

I have rechecked all the configurations like jndiURL and datasource name etc, but no luck.

Can anyone please tell me why this is happening? How Quartz scheduler inserts triggers of one EAR to another EAR database, if I have different configurations in both the EARs, and how can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Please add your datasource configurations

Comment: @tgdavies Datasource configurations? Can you please explain?

Comment: Are the CE and CI configurations really what you think they are? If each instance is using a different DB, then probably everything is fine and you have just misconfigured the datasources.

Comment: @tgdavies yes they are different datasources, each application is using its own database, I have double checked this configuration, and yes that is my question each instance is using a different DB then why scheduler details of application1 which has different configuration but storing their details in another application's DB.

Comment: Look at the configuration of the CE datasource. Is the database where you expect EAR 2 to store its data? Do the same for CI.

Comment: Both the configurations of CE and CI are similar, only change between them are jndi-name and Database Name.